# How would I name these nested elements using BEM?

Tags: html, css, bem

So I have a page like so:

```
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="dashboard-item">
    <div class="dashboard-item__header">
        <span class="dashboard-item__header__icon dashboard-item__header__icon--modifier"></span>Header Title
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-item__content">
        <p class="???"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a dashboard that is my container and it can have different items. An item then has a header and some content, but that item will always be in the dashboard. So, should I really name it **dashboard__item** ?

Also, what about the nested elements like the header and content? Should they use the name dashboard__item__header?

I've read that we should not have nested names like that, but that header should not exist on its own, nor the dashboard item.

So how should I name a case like that?

And in the content, if I have some elements that should look different because they're inside a dashboard item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I really name it dashboard__item ?

It depends. If all the items inside dashboard are very similar and quite simple it's just fine to go with an element of `dashboard`. But if they are different or complicated, you may consider to create separate blocks for each kind of possible items and optionally mix them with `dashboard__item` for positioning purpose (see https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#mixes).

> Should they use the name dashboard__item__header?

No, use something like `dashboard__item-header`. See 
https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-does-bem-not-recommend-using-elements-within-elements-block__elem1__elem2

> if I have some elements that should look different because they're inside a dashboard item?

See second part of this answer https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-should-i-avoid-using-nested-selectors

PS: You hit 3 questions from our FAQ in one post! ;)